# Stop child div resizing when parent div is resized using .resizable()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an example here http://jsfiddle.net/wTtPw/

You can resize the div using jQuery which works fine but I do not want the #spacer to have a fixed with initially because the content of the  can be anything - I do not know the size.

If I remove:

```
width:100px;
```

and then specify a percentage or auto or anything then when you resize the #container div then it also resizes the #spacer div.

Is there anyway I can stop this from happening?

I want the #spacer div to be fixed to the size of the contents inside it and I do not want it to resize when you resize the #container div .

Answer (score 0):

wrap the input in a containing div ie: `#input_container` and make the

```
$("#input_container").resizable();
```

Comment: oh, and remove that width:100px

Comment: and you may want to set `box-sizing:border-box;` on `#myinput`

Comment: I did originally do this but the fact is I do actually want to be able to resize #spacer but I just want the initial size to be whatever the contents is otherwise it expands when I expand #container which I don't want to happen.

Comment: ok - then do as above and then make the spacer resizable programmatically after the DOM loads: `$(function(){$('#spacer').resizable();});`